# MS ODBC C++ detach SQLHSTMT from connection

Tags: odbc

I want to get data from a recordset after disconnecting  db.

Is there such a function in the library? I need the same feature as PutCursorLocation(ADODB::adUseClient) ADO.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

int main() {

    SQLHENV env;
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
    SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);


    SQLHDBC dbc;
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbc);
    SQLDriverConnect(dbc, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydatabase;USER=root;PASSWORD=mypassword;", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);


    SQLHSTMT stmt;
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbc, &stmt);
    SQLExecDirect(stmt, (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT * FROM mytable", SQL_NTS);


**    SQLDisconnect(dbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, dbc);**


    SQLCHAR name[255];
    SQLINTEGER age;
    while (SQLFetch(stmt) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
        SQLGetData(stmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, name, sizeof(name), NULL);
        SQLGetData(stmt, 2, SQL_C_LONG, &age, 0, NULL);
        std::cout << "Name: " << name << ", Age: " << age << std::endl;
    }


    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, env);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the correct C-language variation (`c++`, etc).